# 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'

Tags: nodejs, express

Como puedo redireccionar al usuario a la pagina de inicio y basado en una variable/bandera true/false redireccionarlo a otro url?

Por ejemplo:

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.path === ''){
    res.redirect(302, '/login')

    //Despues de hacer el login debo revisar si la variable es true o false
    if(flag) {
      res.redirect(302, '/error')
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Pero con este código me marca el error:

'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'

Answer (score 0):

el codigo continua ejecutandose dentro del primer if, e intenta mandar una segunda res.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
if(req.path === ''){
  res.redirect(302, '/login') //aqui rediriges al usuario

//Despues de hacer el login debo revisar si la variable es true o false
if(flag) {
  res.redirect(302, '/error') //aqui intentas reenviar otra respuesta, ahi el error que te aparece
}


} else {
next();
  }
})
```

si necesitas comprobar la variable despues de que el usuario haga login, deberias comprobarla en la peticion de login.

si por otro lado la variable flag ya viene en la misma req, podrias directamente incluirlo en el else:

```
else {
  if(req.body.flag){
    res.redirect(302, '/error')
  }
  next();
}
```

Comment: aun así, teniendo en cuenta tu solución, la petición seguirá dando el mismo error

Comment: no la he probado, pero no deberia, la res solo se manda una vez, para eso esta el if principal, pasa por un lado o por otro. del modo original, redirige al usuario y sigue dentro de la primera parte del if, comprobando si existe flag, y si se da el caso, vuelve a enviar la res

Comment: de todos modos pruebalo y me cuentas, la otra opcion, seria comprobar 'flag' en el mismo if(req.path === '' || !flag){.....